# Black Display in Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I installed Xubuntu 13.10 a while ago. Everything was great up until just now when I tried to connect to an external monitor. After connecting the VGA cable from my laptop to the monitor I tried to use the 'Display' option under 'Hardware' in the Settings Manager. It recognised my monitor but when I clicked the 'Use this output' checkbox not only did the monitor remain blank but my laptop's own display also went blank!

Neither removing the VGA cable nor rebooting solved the problem (it would display the login screen but as soon as I log in nothing is displayed). However if I log in as a guest account everything is as expected (I am posting this from the guest account). So my guess would be the Display manager has erroneously set some display option on my account.

What would be the best course of action to get my laptop's screen working on my main account? Also is there some trick I need to know to get dual monitors working? I'd hate to have to boot into Windows every time I need dual monitors...

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the configuration for the second display was stored on:

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml
```

simply delete this file.